# Folder location of Flash cookies on Windows Vista

Tags: windows-vista, flash, cookies

What's the location of the folder that contains the Flash cookies on Windows Vista?

Flash cookies are also known as Local Shared Objects (LSO) and you can see what's been stored and remove them if you go to the [Adobe Flash - Website Storage Settings panel](http://www.macromedia.com/support/documentation/en/flashplayer/help/settings_manager07.html)

Answer (score 12, accepted):

## Adobe Flash Player's Local Shared Objects/Flash cookies location

Also commonly known as "Flash cookies",
 they can be found on Windows XP, Windows Vista and Windows 7 in the following directory:

```
%APPDATA%\Macromedia\Flash Player\#SharedObjects
```

You can also access the [Flash Settings Manager](http://www.macromedia.com/support/documentation/en/flashplayer/help/settings_manager.html) to manage the flash cookies with a UI.

**About %APPDATA%**

It is a [common folder variable](http://www.microsoft.com/security/portal/mmpc/shared/variables.aspx) which translates to configured system paths and makes it easier for you to find locations with alternate paths and/or drive letter configurations.

Usually on Windows Vista and Windows 7 it translates to:

```
C:\Users\<username>\AppData\Roaming\
```

and on Windows XP usually translates to:

```
C:\Documents and Settings\[username]\Application Data\
```

Answer (score 4):

I know [Paul](https://superuser.com/users/3928/p-a-u-l) asked about Vista, but here's the location on **Mac OSX**:

```
/Users/[username]/Library/Preferences/Macromedia/Flash Player/#SharedObjects
```

Copying Flash Cookies from a Win7 installation (thanks to [heavyd's answer](https://superuser.com/questions/31457/what-folder-contains-flash-cookies-on-vista/31461#31461) for the location) to a Mac running OSX 10.5.7 worked fine  :o)

Answer (score 2):

From [here](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Local_Shared_Object), it looks like a cookie would be located at `%APPDATA%\Macromedia\Flash Player\#SharedObjects\<random code>\<domain>\<path>\<object name>.sol`, so I would look in

```
%APPDATA%\Macromedia\Flash Player\#SharedObjects
```

and go from there.

Comment: Yes thanks I found it.
C:\Users\Paul\AppData\Roaming\Macromedia\Flash Player\#SharedObjects\...\...